# How do I encode newline characters in an unencoded img src attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, url-encoding

I have a web service that converts text to an image. I'd like users to be able to write an image tag containing newline characters without encoding the URL (I want the URL to remain legible and easy to edit), for example:

```
<img 
  src="https://webservice/puml/png/
    @startuml
    Alice -> Bob: Hello World!
    @enduml" 
  alt="Diagram of Alice saying Hello World to bob">
```

The problem I'm running into is that the new line characters are encoded as spaces (`%20`) instead of newlines (`%0A`) in Chrome.

I tried to write some simple javascript to automatically encode the URL, but when I check `document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src.indexOf('\n')` the result is `-1`, so I can't do a simple find/replace.

How do I programmatically find and correctly encode the newline characters in the src attribute?